# Standardness Of "Try Back"

Tags: phrasal-verbs, idioms, transitivity

Suppose John went to some office building and inquired with the receptionist about someone that worked there, and that someone happened to be away at that moment.  Then John said to the receptionist:

> I will ***try back*** later.

I could not find "*try back*" in dictionaries.  Could it be a slang phrase?

Comment: easy Google search... [try back](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/try+back)

Comment: @user3169 A student wouldn't recognise that as the same phrase because in the dictionary it's : *try someone back again*. Apart from the *again* there, the problem is that the verb in the dictionary is transitive, but the example is obviously intransitive,. So it's not as surprising as it seems at first that the OP couldn't find it :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty common phrase, so I'm surprised you couldn't find it in a dictionary. That's interesting.

It means "try again," specifically in the context of visits and phone calls. John is going to try visiting again later in the hopes of meeting with the person.

It *is* an idiom of sorts, at least insofar as I wouldn't be able to tell its meaning independently, but I wouldn't go so far as to call it slang. It's not super formal, but it's nothing too abnormal.